# Single Database VS Multiple Databases for ERP Accounting Years Transactions Table?

Tags: c#, sql, database, database-design, schema

We have clients that every year make more than 2 million transactions in a double entry system (daily journal).
Every year all transactions will be posted to the next year's opening balance as a single row for each account without posting any journal entries from the previous year.
Every year starts with an empty transaction journal database.

There are two approaches:
1- multiple databases, one for every year's transactions
2- single database for all transactions by adding a period_year column

Problems in approach 1 (multiple databases):
1- many databases if a client has 10 years of accounting periods
2- if an old year's database is modified it must be posted to newer years' databases
3- if a client is hosted online, there's a restriction on the  number of databases by the hosting provider
4- cross-database query may have problems, e.g. if a client needs a report from years 2016-2018

Problems in approach 2 (single database):
1- very large database size makes our technical support take time for backup & maintenance
2- if technical support updates a journal voucher without using target period_year it may destroy all accounting years
3- slow load in a GUI/UI layer
4- reporting is slow

The second approach may be good if it uses indexes,
which are a good solution for:
-easy maintenance
-high performance
-database size
-cross-query
-GUI/UI responses
-flexible searching & CRUD SQL (update, insert, delete)
-reports & dashboards

Which is the best approach?

Comment: The problems you listed in the 2nd approach are made-up problems.  They are indications of something *else* being wrong, not the table size you've indicated.  Your 1st approach only exists to mask these problems and replace them with other ones, it doesn't actually solve them.

Comment: What part of the problem and solution is C# not database design?

Comment: so ? what`s good solution ? make archive database ? or first approach ? or second approach or what..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question deals with what is known as partitioning and there are several approaches you could take which you will have to investigate the different strategies to fulfill your own specific needs. In my experience, dealing with a similar situation with a similar number of transactions in for some clients many more transactions, there was no need to implement partitioning as all solutions added unnecessary cost and complexity. Instead, all that was needed was to implement indexes and a maintenance plan.

As an alternative the the partitioning approach you describe you could partition transaction data and indexes of a single table by year using SQL Server but the solution could be expensive because it requires Enterprise SQL.

Taking two solutions your are considering, splitting your table into multiple tables isn't going to make the database size smaller. It will at least be the same size because if your single table contains 1 GB of data splitting into two will mean you ave two tables .5 GB each but your database will still be 1GB. In fact it will likely make your database larger because you will need to create additional indexes on the columns you will use to join the tables together. You will also need more complicated logic to query and update the data across multiple years.

The single table approach is most likely going to be the best way to go. It will be the easiest to maintain and develop against and have the lowest overall cost. High performance and GUI responsiveness can be achieved with the correct indexes and maintenance plans on the database. There is no need to cross-query tables.

Comment: Well yes maybe you are true & answer is good, but  ihate to insert new column called Year to attach with current primary key so if i have transaction file contains these columns : Branch , Type, Number  these 3 composite key must added Year column with them to make transactions can get new numbers but for target year :( any alternative for this ?

Comment: I am not sure what your particular needs are. In my experience whenever we deal with transactions for financial or accounting purposes there is at minimum a date column if not a full date and time. You never want to be in a situation where you need to update or remove transactions from a certain time period, perhaps due to an audit or discovery of fraud, and you can't identity the dates of the transaction. In fact nearly every table I create, transactions or otherwise, has at minimum a last modified date, if not a created and last modified, for auditing purposes.

Comment: did you how SAP / Oracle do it... i really fail searching but if you have good approach and provide me real-time ideas will be great . Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the accounting practices used - of the company (because of the trading methods and when they started trading), of the country (legistlation states how long that entity must exist for, and how end-of-year is treated), of the business type (trading forward (Goods on sale or return), trading back (Goods bought/made outright with no financial weight such as loans, trans-ledger and financial instruments), it also depends on the database structure system and how often its transactions are applied to the base - to see how stretched look at how many [non-financial IT] journals have been built since the last apply restore, and run a 'restore truncate' accordingly.

While 'small' these journals can balloon and create a giant backup - have seen a 280Mb database become 3.8Gb overnight because no-one 'truncated' and applied their generated transaction journals - but it can be long running and cannot be interrupted once triggered - the recovery took 75 minutes and became 280Mb again! Journals in this aspect are IT related, and are the system's way of logging what changes are to be applied to the 'base'. At most there should be a low number, more and the system degrades in speed and size. How to do this depends on database - as an example here
 https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCDI_backup_restore_jrnaftbackup .

What this truncate does IS NOT cut the data out but cleans up the holes that have not got a reference back to the 'base' but the system has not yet recognised as being a hole.  In effect, you have backed up space.

As for the journals rolling forward - it depends on the use of the journal and its content - if zero then while the journal is rolled forward, the containing transaction balance is not.  Look for 0 balance journals with no transactions in the prior year or two.Companies like to generate reporting financial journals for a specific project use - but live on after that project has completed, but are empty. Others create a 'mask'. Journal reporting systems that overlays the transactions are another aspect altogether - one system I worked on expanded the journal mask to 38 (thats 38! levels 38x37x36x35x34x33x32x31 ...) in set groups (7,5,12 ...) so was good if right, a nightmare if the wrong reporting journal code used.